# Menu Dropdowns not working - Elementor Header Menu on Wordpress

Tags: php, css, wordpress, custom-wordpress-pages, elementor

[image: Menu Not working on my website]

The header is designed using "Elementor - Header, Footer & Blocks" plugin. The dropdown is not working. Tried activating, deactivating plugin, clearing cache.

Website Link:
https://www.party-monsters.com/

[image: Header settings]

[image: Navigation Menu Settings]

Comment: Menu is not working because it's set to individually links.

Comment: Could you please tell, how to change that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this below code. code goes in your active theme functions.php file.

```
function add_custom_js(){
    ?>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        (function($){
            $(document).ready(function(){
                $('.hfe-has-submenu .hfe-menu-item').on('click',function(e){
                    e.preventDefault();
                    if( $(this).closest('li').find('.sub-menu').css('opacity') === '0' ){
                        $(this).closest('li').find('.sub-menu').css({"visibility": "visible", "opacity": "1"});
                    }else{
                        $(this).closest('li').find('.sub-menu').css({"visibility": "hidden", "opacity": "0"});
                    } 
                });
            });
        })(jQuery);
    </script>
    <?php
}
add_action( 'wp_footer', 'add_custom_js', 10, 1 );
```

Tested and works.

[image]

Comment: Outstanding @bhautik Thank you so much!

Comment: I just changed javascript event from click to mouseover, and it worked like a breeze!

Comment: So is that okay or an issue?

Comment: No that was okay, you're solution worked like a breeze :) Thanks again @bhautik

Comment: Your js code pushing technique is awesome